# Is it trivial to compile standard Intel Debian programs to Arm?

Tags: debian, software-installation, raspberry-pi, make, arm

Is it trivial to compile standard Intel Debian programs to Arm? Am I simplifying this process?

- Take any of my favorite programs ([R Studio](https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/), [Sublime Text](https://www.sublimetext.com/3), [Peek](https://github.com/phw/peek), etc.)
- Find the source code on GitHub or Launchpad
- Grab the list of dependencies or libraries from programs website
- run some make commands
- that's it

And then I can run the program on my Raspberry Pi, or Android tablet, or whatever? Is it this easy to transfer **ANY and/or MOST** Linux programs to Arm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am no expert but this is possible for **most applications**. Whether this is trivial or not depends on the software in question and its dependence on an x86 instruction set. Just looking at [this blog post about getting R Studio on a Raspberry Pi](https://www.r-bloggers.com/rstudio-on-raspberrypi-3/) shows that there are some hurdles.

If you are confident in your abilities in compiling software, go forth and try there is nothing stopping you. Look to see if there already exists an ARM port or alternative for the software you wish to use. There may already exist guides to port the software. If not, once you have successfully ported your software please consider creating the guide or contributing upstream to create a packaged version for others in repos.

Answer (score 2):

Usally it should be possible since 
- Linux ist a well designed os, nearly all hw-dependant stuff is handled at kernel level
- Linux have a posix-compliant systemcall interface
- nearly all Linux driven sw ist build on top of the standard c library

There are some well known ways to do that:
- cross-compile software on a development pc via an arm toolchain (see arm-gnu-eabi packages of your favorite distribution)
- use a rootfile system builder like buildroot or yocto ( both well documented open source projects)
- compile software natively on the target device

If that is trivial depends mostly in your own expierences.